# Rigging a wishbone & piston suspension with bones?

Tags: rigging, objects, rigid-body-simulation

I ultimately want to export this from Blender to Unity, and I know certain rigging parameters don't translate to that very well via .fbx format.

The wishbone and piston should interact with the z-axis of the wheel. The right side of the wishbones and piston should move with the wheel as the wheel goes up/down, while the left side of them be hinged to the frame.

I believe the piston will have a different constraint setup than the wishbones?

Any help appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: See if this is what you're after.  I haven't rigged any armatures, just used a couple of keyframes to move the dish up and down, then used 'Track to' constraints on the arms and piston/cylinder.  If you think this could work in Unity I'll add it and the Blend file as an answer.  The link to a video is - https://www.dropbox.com/s/90sx0ikshwxcnbv/PistonDish.mp4?dl=0  When you get there click on any vacant space in the opening screen to get rid of all the gaff.

Comment: Nice animation, and it's really similar to what I was intending to make. Apparently though, nobody told me that wheels don't behave like the above within unity, and that the animation is all variable-based & no joints in blender are needed.